# How to create a Windows 7 wim image with ImageX

Tags: winpe, imagex

I'm following the book [**MCTS Microsoft Windows 7 Configuration Study Guide: Exam 70-680, Study Guide, 2nd Edition**](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470948450,miniSiteCd-SYBEX.html) to create a Windows image file from a Windows 7 installation.

I've already used *sysprep.exe* to generalize the image. I've created a bootable ISO of WinPE but when I try to use imagex.exe to create the wim file with:

> E:\ImageX.exe /capture C: C:\Images\image.wim “Windows 7” /verify

The following error appears:

> Error opening file [C:\Images\image.wim].
>   The system cannot find the path speficied.

I am not sure where the problem lies as it is my first time doing this. Any help is appreciated.

On another note, is there a way to create the WinPE iso specifiying a es-ES keyboard layout?

Again, thank you.

Comment: WAG: Does the path `C:\Images\ ` exist?

Comment: ... Well that was it. The directory was not created. Thank you.

Comment: Good to know for when I get to that point. (I am currently at page 41 in 70-680's book).

Comment: Might want to post your own answer, just so this question gets an answer and does not stay open (open questions get bumped to the front page every now and then). It might also be best to post the second question in its own post. (How to create the WinPE iso specifiying a es-ES keyboard layout), after searching if a similar question does not yet exist on this site. Possible relevant link to get you started: http://www.windows-noob.com/forums/topic/2348-guide-creating-a-bootimage-with-another-keyboard-layout-winpe-3/

Comment: Is it possible to save image on the same partition which is capturing?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Hennes for the answer](https://superuser.com/questions/972813/how-to-create-a-windows-7-wim-image-with-imagex?noredirect=1#comment1333688_972813).

The problem was that the folder wasn't created:

> mkdir C:\Images
>
> E:\ImageX.exe /capture C: C:\Images\image.wim “Windows 7” /verify

Worked succesfully.